# Conditional formatting of cell, where that cell text value exists in a range of other cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to bold and change text color to red in the the top table, for text match that also exists in the bottom table.

In this case, A, D, and G.

I've been trying variations of this with no success, and would require formatting each cell individually.

```
=MATCH(A1, A8:B12)
=MATCH(A4, A8:B12)
...
=MATCH(B2, A8:B12)
```

Is there a way to do this with a single conditional format?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try CF rule `Custom formula is`-

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,FLATTEN($A$8:$B$12),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Can also try =countif($A$8:$B$12,A1)